# Fastify opentelemetry missing full coverage

Tags: open-telemetry, fastify

We have built a Node.js API based on Fastify and GraphQL. (Without apollo) The API supports gzip compression. The API has an opentelemetry instrumentation which we use to analyse the request times. We can see that there are missing pieces from the graph, after the query is executed. Each GraphQL request gets parsed and then executed. We can see that the database selects (starting with -api: select) run in the query execution. After the query execution is complete, there is more than 50% of the request which is not traced.

Can this time be spent on the serialisation and the compression? Is there a way to add opentelemetry tracing to these parts of the fastify request lifecycle?

[image: Api request opentelemetry]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to add a route level hook this way:

```
    preSerialization: (request, reply, payload, done) => {
      const { tracer } = request.openTelemetry()

      const span = tracer.startSpan(`serialisation`)

      reply.raw.on('finish', () => {
        span.end()
      })

      done(null, payload)
    },
```

This hook will always be executed after the shared `preSerialization` hooks, which means that the the span will contain the time taken from the serialisation to the sending of the data.